# How to dynamically link grpc library c++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to dynamically link the grpc greeting_client example.
I am trying to use the libgrpc++.so, libprotobuf.so.10, libgrpc.so.3,libgrpc++_reflection.so.1 files to do the linking.

I have added these files to my /usr/lib directory and now I am trying to generate executable for greeting_client.

Command I am using is:  `g++ hello.pb.o hello.grpc.pb.o greeting_client.o -L/usr/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed -ldl -o greeting_client -L/usr/local/include/google/ -L/usr/local/include/grpc -L/usr/local/include/grpc++`

Error:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgrpc++_reflection
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the .so files for grpc++_reflection in /usr/lib directory. 
I might be missing something regarding dynamic linking. Can you please point out how to dynamically link the grpc libraries for the example?

Comment: in the compiler arguments you have to add the -I<path_to_grpc_headers>

Comment: But the common.h is header file related with protobuf. 
Can you please tell what changes need to be done to command?

Comment: The problem is the following: The compiler can't figure out the path 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h'. This file should exist somewhere in your computer, and you should tell the compiler by adding the -I<path_to_google_folder>

Comment: This means I will have to install the protobuf. Can't it be done just by using libprotobuf.so file?

Comment: It can, but the SO only have the compiled code of protobuf. This means that the header files (.h) still need to exist, or otherwise your code doesn't know how to call any function of protobuf. So, you don't need to install it, but you still need all .h files in your computer.

Comment: Okay thanks that resolved the error but question still remains how to dynamically link the grpc library? Can you please help regarding that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178211/discussion-between-ricardo-alves-and-prashant-shubham).

Comment: The OP's problem is with the linker, not the compiler, so these comments are actually not correct. He apparently already has the headers in the right place as the code compiles, just doesn't link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I was able to find the solution, The problem is the linker is looking for libgrpc++_reflection.so but I had libgrpc++_reflection.so.14.0.0

A quick hack is to symlink libgrpc++_reflection.so to libgrpc++_reflection.so
The answer lies in the -l option of g++, calling ld. If you look at the man page of this command, you can either do:

```
g++ -l:libgrpc++_reflection.so.14.0.0 [...]
or: g++ -lgrpc++_reflection.so [...] ,
```

if you have a symlink named libgrpc++_reflection.so in your libs path